# Bootstrap Grid arrangement for 3 blocks with different height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

As attached picture showed, that is my target view with response width using Bootstrap, however, the below code couldn't make the position of block 3 just under block 1 before width<sm.
Please tell me how to do, thanks in advance.
[image]

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="height:100px;border:1px solid blue;">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="height:200px;border:1px solid blue;">2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="height:100px;border:1px solid blue;">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```